# Referring an element in json with a - in key

Tags: javascript, json

I've a valid json of the following format.I want to be able to print the value of desc.

```
 var obj = 
    {
        "x-internal": {
            "name": {
                "desc": "abc"
            }
        }
    }

console.log(" Val :"+obj.x-hooks.warehouse.desc);
```

I get a reference error saying hooks is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
 console.log(" Val :"+obj["x-hooks"].warehouse.desc);
```

For clarity, I'm assuming `x-hooks` is in part of `obj`

Comment: it wont with the obj in the question :p